# How to put a tags under each individual img tag

Tags: html, css

Can someone show me how to put text under every individual image and also images must be in same line which is working? I understand that default display for "a" tag is block and  for "img" tag is display inline.
This is my code:

HTML

```
 <div class="other-content">
        <div class="search">
            <h1>We Offer best experience in the world</h1>
            <img src="../Images/beach.jpg" alt="beach" width="200px" height="150px">
            <p>sadasdasd</p>
            <img src="../Images/desert.jpg" alt="desert" width="200px" height="150px">
            <p>sadasdasd</p>
            <img src="../Images/evergreen.jpg" alt="maoutin" width="200px" height="150px">
            <p>sadasdasd</p>
            <img src="../Images/snow-pathway.jpg" alt="snow-pathway" width="200px" height="150px">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
.other-content .search {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.other-content .search p{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the picture with the text in separate divs and make the divs width smaller until the text is below the picture. And with these divs, assign `display:inline-block;`